# Is a GFCI necessary for a dishwasher?

Tags: electrical

I'm wiring in a new dishwasher.  Now that everything is done, I find out that the breakers for my box are not made anymore.  I'm direct wiring it so it will be a dedicated circuit except the garbage disposal will be piggy backing on it.

When my breaker box was designed they didn't have GFCI.  I was able to get a 15amp circuit breaker on Ebay.

MY Q is can I run the dishwasher direct without a GFCI, or should I direct wire an outlet box and then put in a GFCI outlet and plug in the dishwaser and disposal.

PS: The wiring is buried behind the dishwasher and only accessable by pulling out the dishwasher.

If I did have to do an outlet, does the outlet have to be exposed or can I bury it behind the dishwasher.

Comment: If you bury a GFCI receptacle behind the dishwasher, then if it trips how will you reset it? If the next owner doesn't know about it how will they know to reset it? Maybe you could install it under the sink where it can be accessible.

Comment: Do you happen to have a [Federal Pacific](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/41606) panel, which is no longer produced? If so, you might want to consider replacing it (see the video in the accepted answer to the linked question).

Answer (score 7):

According to current code GFCI are required.
They make units that can be wired [dead face GFCI](http://eaglesupply.com//products/specification-grade-blank-face-gfci-ivory-606538?variant=5137918849&gdftrk=gdfV216534_a_7c4330_a_7c15423_a_7c606538&gclid=Cj0KEQiA0sq2BRDRt6Scrqj71vQBEiQAg5bj01gcbWiXgCC8A74VDK-2kWpMrLavPXAB68beiqIUjj0aAvH98P8HAQ) to feed devices not accessible. I have used these under 20$ units in 4 maybe 5 jobs that have passed code inspection on remodels.

Comment: Doesn't current code also require separate circuits for the dishwasher and disposal?

Comment: +1 I would add that this is correct but most areas near me still go by the NEC 2008 which I don't think it is required there.  Also is an AFCI OK in lieu?

Answer (score 0):

Since you replaced/modified the wiring you will need to put a GFCI in route, preferably below the panel.